# what's the purpose of encoding and decoding at the same line of code?

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, decoding

I have seen code in which string is encoded and immediately decoded? What benefit does it give?

I have come across code a few times that goes like below. What's its purpose?

```py
string_to_hash = "ahmer"
base64_string = base64.b64encode(string_to_hash).decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

b64encode takes bytes and returns bytes. Ideally it should be:

```
base64_string = base64.b64encode(string_to_hash.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
```

string -> bytes -> b64encoded bytes -> b64 encoded string

Comment: Why does we have to decode at the end? I meant what's the point of applying encoding function if we decode it immediately.

Comment: encode("utf-8") stands for 'unicode string' to bytes; decode("utf-8") stands for bytes to  'unicode string'. These two encode/decode has nothing to do with b64encode/b64decode.